# Orthogonal complement of direct sum of two orthogonal spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are orthogonal Hilbert subspaces. To find the orthogonal complement of the direct sum with projections, is the following true?

\begin{equation}
(A \bigoplus B)^\perp = \prod(A^\perp | B^\perp),
\end{equation}
where $\prod(A^\perp | B^\perp)$ is the projection of $A^\perp$ onto $B^\perp$.

Comment: What is this notation on the right hand side? Anyway it should simply be $A^\perp\cap B^\perp$.

Comment: I have made the question hopefully clearer.

Comment: No, not any cleaner. I would use e.g. $p_A$ and $p_B$ for the projections and both have the whole ambient space as domains.